# HAProxy 1.6 configuration Node.js ssh server child process

Tags: node.js, ssh, haproxy

I am running a Node.js SSH server that spawns a child process to exec code (using `require('child_process').spawn`) after successful authentication.

The client server connections works fine on port 22 and connection is kept alive successfully through spawned process.

I am trying to setup up now with HAProxy 1.6, to forward port 22 to a non-privileged port on which the SSH server is listening.

However, when the child process is spawned the server either errors `Error: write EPIPE` or `Error: read ECONNRESET`.

This suggests to me there is an issue with prematurely closed stream or connection between the client -> HAProxy -> server?

I am looking at [websocket configurations](http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/11/07/websockets-load-balancing-with-haproxy/) and [ssh configurations](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/setting-up-ssh-port-forwarding-776640364.html) for HAProxy and various keep alive options.  However I cannot get the connection to work.

My configuration:

```
global
  daemon
  maxconn 10000
  log 127.0.0.1 local0

defaults
  log global
  option tcplog
  option logasap
  timeout connect 500s
  timeout client 5000s
  timeout server 2h
  timeout server-fin 5000s
  timeout client-fin 5000s
  timeout tunnel 1h
  option tcpka

frontend sshd
  bind *:22
  default_backend ssh
  timeout client 2h

backend ssh
  mode tcp
  server ssh2server 127.0.0.1:5000 check port 5000
```

Any pointers or help would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

EDIT
Runing haproxy in debug mode I have
`00000000:sshd.accept(0004)=0005 from [my ip]
00000000:ssh.srvcls[0005:0006]
00000000:ssh.clicls[0005:0006]
00000000:ssh.closed[0005:0006]`.

On the tcplog
`Oct 15 15:15:38 localhost haproxy[16036]: 128.277.13.23:51146 [15/Oct/2016:15:15:38.804] sshd ssh/ssh2server 1/0/+0 +0 -- 1/1/1/1/0 0/0`

Comment: Start with the HAProxy log.  What do you see?

Comment: Runing haproxy in debug mode I have `00000000:sshd.accept(0004)=0005 from [my ip]
00000000:ssh.srvcls[0005:0006]
00000000:ssh.clicls[0005:0006]
00000000:ssh.closed[0005:0006]`.  On the tcplog, `Oct 15 15:15:38 localhost haproxy[16036]: 128.277.13.23:51146 [15/Oct/2016:15:15:38.804] sshd ssh/ssh2server 1/0/+0 +0 -- 1/1/1/1/0 0/0`

Comment: According to this, your server daemon is accepting then closing the connection, with HAProxy working normally.  However... I would suggest that your server daemon isn't correctly handling the health check from HAProxy.  To verify, remove `check port 5000` and see what happens, then.